# How to get HttpContext in configure method in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, coreclr

I have asp.net core application and I want current HttpContext in configure method. So i am passing `IHttpContextAccessor` to configure method.  Something like below

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, 
                      IApplicationLifetime appLifetime, IServiceProvider services, 
                      IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{    
           var request = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request;    
}
```

However httpContextAccessor.HttpContext is always null

Comment: Configure runs when the service starts. Is there ever going to be a http context at that point? Has a request even happened? I *feel* like it would not. Or, am I confused on how I think this would work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does not work because there is no HTTP-request (as R.Richards pointed out) when your application starts. `Configure` is called by the runtime when the application starts, not when the first request is handled.

Please take a look at the documentation about application startup: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup.

Comment: Thanks. I have changed my approach and i created a custom middleware. The Invoke method inthe middleware has httpContext as parameter